# error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1 in edx devstack, vagrant, virtualbox

Tags: python, django, vagrant, edx, openedx

I am trying to run edx devstack lms on my localhost using virtualbox, vagrant.
When I try to run a command on vagrant instance in ubuntu, python env generates the error below:

`error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: exit from edx-platform and run `sudo apt-get install swig` on vagrant instance solve my problem